What is an irreducible necklace?
In my abstract algebra class, the following question is on my homework assignment:

Let $q = p^k$ where $p$ and $k$ are both prime, and choose a monic
polynomial $m(x) \in (\mathbb{Z}/p)[x]$ of degree $k$ at random. Show that the
probability that m(x) is irreducible is very close to 1/k when q is
large, i.e., that $$ \lim_{q\to\infty} k\text{Pr}[m(x) \text{
> irredcible}] = 1 $$

We are then give the following hint and note:

What this is really about is counting the number of relevant
irreducible polynomials $m(x)$ of degree $k$, equivalently the number
of irreducible necklaces of degree k with p colors. The conclusion
holds whether or not k is prime, only it is easier to do the
calculation when k is a prime or a prime power.

I understand that necklace of a polynomial $f(x) \in (\mathbb{Z}/p)[x]$ of degree $n$ has $n$ beads and $p$ different possible colors for the beads. However, I haven't been able to make any progress on the question because I am stuck as to what an irreducible necklace means. Obviously, it means the corresponding polynomial is irreducible; but how is it easier to find an irreducible necklace than to find an irreducible polynomial.
I understand that there are $k^p$ possible necklaces to represent the monic polynomials of degree $k$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p)[x]$ and I assume that the answer is based on finding there are $\sim k^{p-1}$ of these are irreducible, but I don't know how to get here.

First consider the case $k=v^r$ for some prime number $v$.  Then the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ contains $p^k$ elements, of which $p^{k/v}$ belong to its maximal subfield.
The remaining $p^k-p^{k/v}$ elements are each a root of a unique monic, degree $k$, irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$.  As we do not get repeated roots for irreducible polynomials over finite fields, each of the irreducible polynomials will account for precisely $k$ elements of the field.  Thus the number of monic, irreducible polynomials of degree $k$, over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is precisely $$\frac{p^k-p^{k/v}}{k}.$$
As there are $p^k$ degree $k$ monic polynomials altogether, we see that the probability that a randomly chosen monic degree $k$ polynomial is indeed asymptotically $1/k$ in the required sense.
If $k$ is not a prime power, then we have more than one maximal subfield.  Thus to remove all elements of the maximal subfields (e.g. elements whose minimal polynomial is of degree less than $k$), we must use the inclusion-exclusion principle, to find the number of irreducible polynomials:
$$\frac1k(p^k-p^{k/{v_1}}-p^{k/{v_2}}-\cdots+p^{k/{(v_1v_2)}}+p^{k/{(v_1v_3)}}+\cdots-p^{k/{(v_1v_2v_3)}}-\cdots)$$
$$=
\frac1k\sum_{n|k} \mu(n)p^{k/n},
$$
where $\mu$ is the Mobius function.  It is clear that the $n=1$ term $P^K$ dominates this sum for large $k$ (as the other terms are bounded by $\sqrt{p^k}$ and there are fewer than $k=\log_p(p^k)$ of them), so again we get that the probability of a random monic polynomial of degree $k$ being irreducible is indeed asymptotically $\frac1k$ for large $k$.
The analogy with beaded necklaces is that there are $p^k$ ways to arrange $k$ beads (from a set of $p$ colours) along a line, just as there are $p^k$ elements in $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$.  The number of sequences that repeat every $k/v$ beads, is the same as the number of elements in $\mathbb{F}_{p^{k/v}}$.  Further the number of patterns that repeat with several frequencies is the same as the number of elements in the corresponding intersection of subfields.
Finally, we can count the number of non-repeating patterns going around a circular necklace, by dividing the number of non-repeating patterns in a line, by $k$.  Thus we would get the same formula for this, as we got for irreducible polynomials, above.
